# Writing a condition for child objects with includes and where method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently I got this:

```
Country.includes(products: [:categories]).where("products.categories.name = ?", "Gardening").references(products: [:categories])
```

Is there something wrong with this code? Or we are not allowed to write condition for 2nd level child objects?

Comment: Does it work? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same answer by using
[Different ways of eager loading](http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/)

```
r = Country.joins(products: [:categories]).where("products.categories.name = ?", "Gardening").preload(products: [:categories])
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple just do

```
Country.joins(products: [:categories]).where("categories.name = ?", "Gardening")
```

or:

```
Country.joins(products: [:categories]).where(categories: {name: "Gardening"})
```